# Custom event on object to change button state

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I have 3 buttons on my Data Entry form, OK, APPLY, CANCEL.

This form is used to edit a doctor's details, things like first name, phone # etc...

I have one object doctorObj which at any given time is either empty (a new doctor) or an object pulled from a Linq query.

I deep clone the doctorObj to EditCopyDoctor which is of the same type but used for form editing (so if Cancel is hit, the database do not need to update).

What I want to achieve is observe the EditCopyDoctor for changes against the original doctorObj so

```
If(doctor.Changed() && doctor.IsNotNew)
{
ApplyButton.Enabled = true;
}
else
{
ApplyButton.Enabled = false;
}
```

So I thought writting an event to trigger when something changed on EditCopyDoctor is the best way to do it but I'm not sure how.

I can of course put the ApplyButton.Enabled code in the TextChanged events from the form but I was wondering if there are any quicker ways to do this, I don't really want to do this as there are 10+ textbox and other controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your "Doctor" type sounds like it's generated by LINQ to SQL/Entities you should find that it already implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Therefore, you should just need to watch the `PropertyChanged` event and act accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Reddog, can you help me by posting a code example on how to watch the PropertyChanged event inside the form, sorry I'm very new.

Comment: I guess that answer all depends on how you are binding your data object to the UI (e.g. binding source? direct? something else?) and also which "LINQ To" system you are using.